# CCLabelTTF::setString with a string include full shape punctuation cause CCImage::~CCImage() crash in Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

To repeat this crash, first we need a string, like

```
"blabla...bla　"
             ^
             here is a full shape blank space. Other full shape punctuation also cause this crash, such as `！`, `・`.
```

Second, we need a CCLabelTTF, and

```
setDimensions(const CCSize &dim)
setString(const char *string) // use the string above
```

Then, if and only if the only full shape blank space happened to be displayed in another new line, it would crash.

The crash log is as following:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
Stack frame #00  pc 0000f41c  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame #01  pc 000121c3  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1458)
Stack frame #02  pc 0000d333  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
Stack frame #03  pc 006ecc60  /data/app-lib/jp.co.gu3.allen-1/liballen.so (cocos2d::CCImage::~CCImage()+128): Routine ~CCImage in /Users/tangyue/project/crosskaiser-native-android/application/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:91
Stack frame #04  pc 006eccc8  /data/app-lib/jp.co.gu3.allen-1/liballen.so (cocos2d::CCImage::~CCImage()+20): Routine ~CCImage in /Users/tangyue/project/crosskaiser-native-android/application/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/platform/CCImageCommon_cpp.h:92
Stack frame #05  pc 00684234  /data/app-lib/jp.co.gu3.allen-1/liballen.so (cocos2d::CCObject::release()+204): Routine release in /Users/tangyue/project/crosskaiser-native-android/application/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.cpp:86
Stack frame #06  pc 007230a8  /data/app-lib/jp.co.gu3.allen-1/liballen.so (cocos2d::CCTexture2D::initWithString(char const*, char const*, float, cocos2d::CCSize const&, cocos2d::CCTextAlignment, cocos2d::CCVerticalTextAlignment)+624): Routine initWithString in (null):0
Stack frame #07  pc 006b0488  /data/app-lib/jp.co.gu3.allen-1/liballen.so (cocos2d::CCLabelTTF::updateTexture()+308): Routine updateTexture in /Users/tangyue/project/crosskaiser-native-android/application/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/label_nodes/CCLabelTTF.cpp:275
Stack frame #08  pc 006afeb8  /data/app-lib/jp.co.gu3.allen-1/liballen.so (cocos2d::CCLabelTTF::setString(char const*)+204): Routine setString in /Users/tangyue/project/crosskaiser-native-android/application/proj.android/../../cocos2dx/label_nodes/CCLabelTTF.cpp:144
```

In `CCImageCommon_cpp.h:91`, it is :

```
CCImage::~CCImage()
{
    CC_SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(m_pData);
}
```

So if anybody can help me or give some suggestion, I should be grateful.

The device is samsung Galaxy S4 SC-04E.

cocos2d-x version is cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem exactly is.

See this [commit in cocos2d-x project](https://github.com/waiter/cocos2d-x/commit/fd60e23319d48c473540d21b8d31bb06c3bfb2cc) and [these issues](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/search?q=cclabelttf+setstring&type=Issues).

The simple code cause the big problem which took me lots of time :(

Help this can help some other people as poor as me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem in using CCLabelTTF,I found if you have set the Dimensions,make sure the end of last line must not be \n.

I can't find out reason ,I change my font size and crash gone.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I firstly solved this problem with this similar way, but later on I faced more and more crashes that make me crazy, and finally found the reason. You can look my answer below.(PS: I forgot my this post, so post the solution just now.)